# bootstrap carousel: determine width of inactive caption

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-carousel

I want to determine the width of the captions of the different slides. Actually, it's not a huge problem I thought as the procedure is quite clear for me. Nonetheless, I came across an obstacle. That is to say: I can only calculate the width of the current active slide. The width of the inactive slides will always be 0. Is there a way to calculate the width of the inactive slides? Here is a [demo](http://www.bootply.com/ykaxVKryd8)
When setting the active class to a different item manually, then the width of this item will be calculated. Just have a look at the console.

Answer (score 0):

I've just found a solution on my own. I solved it by adding temporarily the active class to those items not having it, calculated the width and then removed the class again. Here the [code](http://www.bootply.com/GyZjFfYFn3).
If any body should have a better solution, please don't hesitate to share it.